# Python - create new dictionary if condition from another dictionary is met

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries `conj_dict` and `score_dict`. The keys of both dictionaries are the same.

I would like to create a new dictionary with all the key pairs of `conj_dict` that have a value in `score_dict` of less than 2.

```
conj_dict = {
  "'Essere' PR 1": 'sono',
  "'Essere' PR 2": 'sei',
  "'Essere' PR 3": 'e',
  "'Essere' PR 4": 'siamo',
  "'Essere' PR 5": 'siete',
  "'Essere' PR 6": 'sono'
    }

score_dict = {
  "'Essere' PR 1": 0,
  "'Essere' PR 2": 2,
  "'Essere' PR 3": 1,
  "'Essere' PR 4": 0,
  "'Essere' PR 5": 0,
  "'Essere' PR 6": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use a dict comprehension with a condition:

```
new_dict = {
    key: value for (key, value) in conj_dict.items() if score_dict[key] < 2 
}
```

Comment: Makes me wonder at what percentage this and `{key: conj_dict[key] for key in conj_dict if score_dict[key] < 2}` are equally fast...

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Was able to finish the script I was writing and it made my day! :)

Answer (score -1):

Make an empty dict and loop over either dictionary and use the key to access the respective values of each.

```
d = {}
for k, v in conj_dict.items():
    if(score_dict.get(k) < 2): d[k] = conj_dict.get(k)
```

OR

```
d = {}
for k, v in score_dict.items():
    if(score_dict.get(k) < 2): d[k] = conj_dict.get(k)
```

Showcasing functionality of
[all values of score < 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m7iP.png)